# Twitter OAuth respond 403 http_code

Tags: php

I have set proper `CONSUMER_KEY`,`CONSUMER_SECRET`,`OAUTH_CALLBACK` and also SSL certificate installation but still I got 403 as http_code in response:

```
  $connection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET);
  $request_token = $connection->getRequestToken($redirectUrl);
  print_r($connection);
  exit
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you added the redirect_uri in the twitter application settings. Please check the settings and add if it is not added.

Also note if your URL has any space use "urlencode()". If the path has any underscore(_) try to rename that and try it. It may work.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks ,i forgot to add callback url in settings
Now it's working well

Comment: Great @AnandPatel All the best in coding.

And mark the answer the "useful" :)